# How to call QueryLocator.iterator() twice

Tags: database, querylocator

I am using a QueryLocator in my code. In one part of the code I call the .iterator() method to verify that it is not empty. Now I am going through writing a unit test and finding that I am unable to call .iterator() on the same QueryLocator twice. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong? Here is some anonymous apex to explain what I mean:

> Database.QueryLocator queryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT
>   Id FROM Contact LIMIT 10]);
>
> Database.QueryLocatorIterator it1 = queryLocator.iterator();
>
> System.debug(it1.hasNext());
>
> Database.QueryLocatorIterator it2 = queryLocator.iterator();
>
> System.debug(it2.hasNext());

When I execute this (and I have Contacts in my DB), then the first debug will say true and then the next one says false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm) has the following to say about `iterator`:

> To iterate over a query locator, save the iterator instance that this method returns in a variable and then use this variable to iterate over the collection. Calling iterator every time you want to perform an iteration can result in incorrect behavior because each call returns a new iterator instance.

What that seems to mean is that you can only call `iterator()` once per `QueryLocator`.  Since you are just interested in whether `hasNext` is true, just save the iterator and call `hasNext` twice (or save the result in a boolean).  If you need to iterate over the collection twice, you may need to save each record in a `List` for later use.

Comment: Thanks although I prefer not to save this iterator solely for testing purposes. I would not mind if Salesforce would do what it says and give me a new iterator instance rather than just an empty iterator.